# Trouble converting refernced function to pointer function. (Expression must have pointer-to-class type but has "insert object here"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers

So, full admission, I am new to C++, and I don't really get pointers entirely. I started these methods using just references, and it complied fine. But once I changed the vector to a vector that holds pointers to objects instead of just objects, things just aren't working the way they are supposed to. I've tried looking through my book for anything, but it really only briskly covers pointers. So, I'm here without much a clue of what I am mucking up. The goal is to simply have the vector hold pointers to the characterbase objects that were made. Pc and enemy. Then the for code display and set values that the pointer held in the array, well, points too. I thought it might be an easy go, but something's clearly the matter. The sort comparator I made, even when removing the for methods, crashes when I test it. Just err, pointers (pun intended) in the right direction would be helpful.

```
void EVoot::IRollTwoCombatantsPtrs(CharacterBase& PC, CharacterBase& Enemy) {

CharacterBase* player_ptr = nullptr;
CharacterBase* enemy_ptr = nullptr;
player_ptr = &PC;
enemy_ptr = &Enemy;

std::vector<CharacterBase*> ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray;
ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.push_back(player_ptr);
ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.push_back(enemy_ptr);


sort(ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.begin(), ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.end(), [&](const CharacterBase& Char1, const CharacterBase& Char2)
    {

        //First Argument Stays First (Return true)
        if (Char1.getCharacterInitiative() < Char2.getCharacterInitiative())
        {
            return true;
        }
        //First Argument goes Next (Swap) (Return false)
        if (Char1.getCharacterInitiative() > Char2.getCharacterInitiative())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (Char1.getCharacterInitiative() == Char2.getCharacterInitiative())
        {
            engineFeedback = engineFeedback + " \n Error, matching initiative values found between " + Char1.getCharacterName() + " and " + Char2.getCharacterName();
        }

    });

//The order needs to be reversed so that the highest turn order appears first.
reverse(ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.begin(), ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.end());

TurnOrderArraySize = ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.size();
engineFeedback = engineFeedback + "\nTurn Order Array Size: " + std::to_string(TurnOrderArraySize);
//Set Turn orders now and provide a readout of the values for each item within the character Turn Order Array.
for (auto iterator = ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.begin(); iterator != ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.end(); iterator++) {
engineFeedback = engineFeedback + "\n Name: " + iterator.getCharacterName() + " Initiative: " + std::to_string(*iterator->getCharacterInitiative()) + " Player Character Flag: " + std::to_string(iterator->getIsPlayerCharacter());
iterator->setCharacterTurnOrder(iterator - ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.begin() + 1);
engineFeedback = engineFeedback + "\nTurn Order: " + std::to_string(iterator->getCharacterTurnOrder());
}

  }

CharacterBase::CharacterBase() {

  }
  
 double CharacterBase::getCharacterInitiative() const
 {
return cInitiative;
 }




   void CharacterBase::setCharacterInitiative(double sInitiative)
  {
    cInitiative = sInitiative;
     }

 //gets the Character's turn order
 int CharacterBase::getCharacterTurnOrder() const
  {
return cTurnOrder;
 }


   //sets the Character's turn order
 void CharacterBase::setCharacterTurnOrder(int sTurnOrder)
  {
cTurnOrder = sTurnOrder;
}

 double cInitiative;
 int cTurnOrder;
```

Comment: please include the complete verbatim error message in the quesiton. And try to post a [mcve]

Comment: Normally my Character object instance is stored in an entirely different file. My original method does what it needs to, but the changes it makes are lost when another method is called. So, the changes I need to be made are not permanent, and only happen within that single function call. I figured a pointer would fix this.

Comment: you try to sort a vector of pointers with a comapator that does not take pointers `[&](const CharacterBase& Char1, const CharacterBase& Char2)`

Comment: I stopped reading after two sentences. I recommend reviewing [ask], in particular the parts about getting to the point. Start with your question, and save the excuses for the end.

Comment: your code is a lot too complicated.  Really a lot. There is so much code, populating a vector, a call to `sort`, a call to `reverse`, and all that only to see which of two objects returns the larger value from a member method. Try to stay simple. Even as beginner, If things look too complicated then chances are that things are just too complicated and can be done is a simpler way.

Comment: And your comment is another misunderstanding. " [...] I figured a pointer would fix this." No. Pointers are rarely the solution. You can work on the references that get passed to the funciton. No need for pointless use of pointers. I suppose in the orginial code you populated the vector with copies of the objects, and copies are copies. But you do not need the copies or the vector in the first place

Comment: Thank you for the advice 463035818, it's appreciated. Especially for somebody still getting to grips with this language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is that your ordering function wants two references, but the vector contains pointers.
(You're also failing to return a value on one path; comparing two equivalent values *must* return `false`, but that's undefined behaviour and not a compilation error.)

You could fix that, but you have a whole lot of complicated code essentially just for determining which of two numbers is the greatest.
Here is one suggestion for simplifying it:

```
std::string turnFeedback(const CharacterBase& c)
{
    std::ofstream os;
    os << "\n Name: " << c.getCharacterName()
       << " Initiative: " << c.getCharacterInitiative()
       << " Player Character Flag: " << c.getIsPlayerCharacter()
       << "\nTurn Order: " << c.getCharacterTurnOrder();
    return os.str();
}

void EVoot::IRollTwoCombatantsPtrs(CharacterBase& PC, CharacterBase& Enemy) {
    auto pcValue = PC.getCharacterInitiative();
    auto enemyValue = Enemy.getCharacterInitiative();
    if (pcValue == enemyValue)
    {
        engineFeedback = engineFeedback + " \n Error, matching initiative values found between "
                       + PC.getCharacterName() + " and " + Enemy.getCharacterName();                
    }
    else
    {
        auto pcWins = pcValue > enemyValue;
        CharacterBase& first = pcWins ? PC : Enemy;
        CharacterBase& second = pcWins ? Enemy : PC;
        first.setCharacterTurnOrder(1);
        second.setCharacterTurnOrder(2);
        engineFeedback += turnFeedback(first);
        engineFeedback += turnFeedback(second);
    }
}
```